# syncOrchestrator.Synchronize(); throws an Exception

Tags: database, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework

I successfully done with provision on both side client and server

```
 1  clientProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(clientConn, tableScope);
 2  if (!clientProvision.ScopeExists("Scope1"))
 3      clientProvision.Apply();
 4  else
 5      messagebox("Scope already exist on client side");
 6
 7  serverProvision = new SqlSyncScopeProvisioning(serverConn, tableScope);
 8  if (!serverProvision.ScopeExists("Scope1"))
 9      serverProvision.Apply();
 10  else
 11      messagebox("Scope already exist on server side");
```

and when I call this code for the first time `1st if(line no. 2)` and `2nd if(line no. 8)` gets executed and if I call this code 2nd time then `1st else(line no.4)` get executed as client is `already provisioned` but here it execute `2nd if(line no. 8)` instead of executing `2nd else(line no. 10)` and `throws an exception at line no. 9 serverprovision.Apply(); "There is already an object named 'schema_info' in the database."`

And if i try to synchronize then it throws an exception at line `syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();` `"The current operation could not be completed because the database is not provisioned for sync or you not have permissions to the sync configuration tables."`

Is this privilege problem or anything else. If this is privilege problem then why it is allow provision for the 1st time?????

```
-- Server Side DB(database1) --   

database1.TableName_tracking

dbo.TableName

-- Client Side DB(database1) --

dbo.TableName_tracking

dbo.TableName
```

Comment: can you check under which schema were the sync fx objects created? (i.e., dbo?)

Comment: there are different schema on both side...but i don't know how to create schema on server side

Comment: am not referring to table schema, am referring to an schema object such us dbo or whatever user defined schema you have...

Comment: i dont have user defined schema...but i have dbo schema by default on local db and database name on server side...

Comment: I just edited my question...there I have given how my tables appears in database...as i am fresher i am not good in database...please guide me how to solve this one

Comment: can you take a screen shot of your table listing for both client and server in SQL Management Studio?

Comment: I am new member here i dont have sufficient reputation to post image here

Comment: deprovision your database and set the schema via the ObjectSchema property (e.g., ObjectSchema = "dbo")

Comment: ohhhhhh its working...thank you very much..one more quest. how to grant permission to alter database on godaddy site because i was trying to do synchronization by hosting my DB on godaddy but it was showing me an error that you donnot have permission to alter DB

Comment: ALTER DATABASE [database name] SET ALLOW_SNAPSHOT_ISOLATION ON

Comment: when i execute this query it shows error "User does not have permission to alter database 'DatabaseName', the database does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access checks. ALTER DATABASE statement failed."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was just schema problem...schema on both side was different...i just added code

```
ServerProvision.ObjectSchema=".dbo";
```

and it worked fine for me Thanks JuneT